# How do you prove that this set is open?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, low-dimensional-topology

$$a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} $$
$$
A = \{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3} / ax + by + cz + d > 0 \}
$$

I need to get this proof by definition, but I have ran into trouble trying to work with the difinition in $\mathbb{R^3}$, as I have no previous experience in that space.

Comment: What have you attempted thus far? Also, what are the values of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$?

Comment: Can you get it as an inverse image of an open under an obvious continuous function?

Comment: I have now edited it and included what a,b,c, and d are. I have tried to prove it by definition, as that is the way I am meant to do it, but haven't figured out yet what's the right procedure to achieve it.

Comment: @UxíoGarcíaAndrade ... which raises the question of what definition(s) and results you're allowed to use.

Comment: $$A open \Leftrightarrow \forall x \in A  \exists ε>0 : B(x,ε)\subset A$$

Comment: I'm allowed to use just definitions and basic properties of open sets.

Comment: Is your definition of "open set" based on  general topology (one of the tags used)? If so then how about the hint of @Mathematician42?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an arbitrary point $P(x_0, y_0,z_0 )$in $$A = \{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3} / ax + by + cz + d > 0 \}$$

The open ball centered at P and radius $$ \delta = \frac {| ax_0+by_0 +cz_0-d|}{ 2\sqrt {a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$ is entirely in A.

Thus A is an open set.

Answer (score 1):

A set is open iff its complement is closed.

The complement of $$A = \{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3} / ax + by + cz + d > 0 \}$$ is $$B = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3} : ax + by + cz + d \le 0 \}$$

Note that B is the space under and including the plane $$ ax + by + cz + d =0$$ which is its boundary, so B is closed.

Comment: I like this answer the best, by the way. It is the most understanding and simplest, imho :)

Comment: Hahaha ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Well spotted that you can understand this complement geometrically, but I do not agree that this is the simplest and best way to solve these kind of problems. This method would fail if we had the condition $ax^2+by+cz+d>0$ whereas the other one still works.

Comment: I have sent another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment of @Mathematician 42, observe that $A=f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ where $f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz+d.$ But $f$ is formed by addition of scalar multiples of three projection maps and a constant. Further, $(0,\infty)$ is an open set in $\Bbb R$. This means...

Comment: Can't be much easier than this, right?

Comment: @Mathematician42 Lol!